# How to switch sound output source?

Tags: 20.04, sound

By default I have sound going through the headphones. When I switch output source in the settings - every sound is still going through the headphones. Test sounds like "front left", "front right" played on headphones too. But alert sounds played on speakers correctly. The trouble is not in speakers. I cannot switch the output source to something else too.